# Updated Android Studio, Logcat not working on one Android device anymore but still works on my other Android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

I googled this a lot so I believe it is appropriate to create a new question.

I updated Android Studio recently and my main Android device (ZTE, not an emulator) stopped reporting to Logcat. This device has never had a problem reporting to Logcat.

I tried all the steps from restarting my Android, to restarting Logcat, to restarting Android Studio, to Invalidate Catches / Restart... to refreshing the gradle to even resetting the Android device to factory settings. I of course checked the Logcat filters and the developer options on the phone like a 100 times.

The part which is weird to me is my other Android device (HTC) still reports to Logcat just fine with no problems at all. *This means its not Android Studio, its the ZTE phone itself.*

Does anyone have an idea why my ZTE wont report to Logcat anymore but my HTC has no problem reporting to Logcat after updating Android Studio? By the way I'm 99% sure its not the developer options on the ZTE as they match the developer options on the HTC exactly.

Comment: Have you run logcat via the command line?  Its far more likely that there's some problem with connecting to the device via adb than a problem with logcat itself.For that matter, if you run adb devices does it recognize the device is attached?

Comment: I tried to restart adb from there and also did 'adb devices' and both the phones showed up.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have a ZTE tablet and it's not showing anything at all in the Logcat whilst the other devices are showing fine.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had to get a new phone to test. Although I just updated Android Studio to 3.4 maybe that will help? Haven't checked yet.

Comment: hey did you find any solution ? @MarcAlexander ? i have a ZTE too and its not showing logcat too

Comment: @faiizii Nope. I even tried on 3 different computers, reset the phone and plenty more. Ended up getting a new phone.

Comment: Haha  head of to Google  Google knows how to sell their devices 

Answer (score 3):

## You can fix the following loop through this

- Restart logcat
- Change the log level to Debug (or anything else) and back to Verbose.
- unplugging and plugging back in the device
- running adb kill-server && adb start-server
- Close Android Studio and launch ddms on the command line.
- Restart Android Studio
  And finally restarting the computer if all else fails.

## The problem is intermittent, I think Android Studio is just buggy.

Comment: Take a look at my post.. I tried all these except restarting my computer and close Android Studio and launch ddms on the command line.. I'll try those. Can you provide instructions on how to launch ddms on the command line?

Comment: I think this may help in this https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: I did ctrl+f ddms and found nothing on that link. I know about logcat and adb, I'm asking about ddms.

Comment: ddms has been deprecated in latest version of android .You can use Android device manager. This may help https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor

Comment: Also you acn try the other alternative as specified by me in the other answer

Answer (score 1):

[image: Change to no filter]

## Try changing to no filters

It is also one alternative

Comment: Already set to No Filters and is on the correct device to the left with no luck. From the question: " of course checked the Logcat filters and the developer options on the phone like a 100 times.". Thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like studio issue. Can you try changing the device USB configuration to MTP and authorise the device and toggle debugging option turning on/off.